# Computer starts only when power switch is turned off momentarily

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, shutdown, power

I can use my computer without any issues but I have to follow weird procedure to start it.

If you turn the power switch on and press CPU power button it won't start as it normally should. I have to do following

- Turn the power switch on
- Press CPU power button
- Momentarily (very short period, may be few hundred milliseconds) shut off the power switch
- Computer starts

Here momentary shutting down power supply is achieved using mechanical switch and trying to turn it on and off continuously. At some point it achieves required small period of time in shut off position (as I said very brief time) and computer starts.

I have done this for more than a year now, and it works without too much effort most of the time. Sometimes it takes more time. What can be the reason for this?

I am using P5G41T M-LX motherboard, and it had some issues in the past like broken audio because of voltage surge probably.

Comment: Sounds like it's time for a new PSU...

Comment: I remember trying out few old PSUs apart from this but having similar issue. But still I can verify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functionality of service buttons (PwrOn, Reset) is provided by a section of mainboard's ICH (aka "South Bridge" ) powered from always-on +5VSB (standby) voltage. You need to check for quality of this rail.

The rail can have a problem on PSU side, or it could be overloaded by excessive amount of bus-powered USB devices. Or it could be a gradual deterioration (fatigue) of ICH chip itself (or partial damage due to ESD event).

To check if the PSU is good, plug the PSU into AC outlet without connecting to mainboard or anything else. Its 20/25 pin connector must have the +5VSB pin (pin9, violet) delivering +5V relative to ground wires (black wires). It should hold +5V with at least 2A load (on a 2.5 Ohm resistor).

If PSU is good, connect it to bare mainboard, and check if this rail is affected.